# Empty content.jar after mirroring Eclipse Kepler repository

Tags: java, eclipse, repository, eclipse-kepler, p2

I have a scheduled job, which is mirroring the P2 Kepler repository (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/). The mirroring seems successful but i if i open the "install new software" dialog in Eclipse and pointing it to the mirrored directory there is nothing to install.

I compared the Kepler Repository with the Indigo Repository and recognized that the content.jar has a big difference. While in the indigo repository the size of the content.jar is about 5MByte, the content.jar in the Kepler Repository is only 300Byte. This difference occurs because the content.xml for the Kepler Release is empty!

Is this a bug? How can i make it work? I wanna be able to install all kepler components from the "install new software" dialog.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Probably you mirror only the artifact repository. Please show how do you initialize the mirroring job.

Answer (score 0):

I am executing following commands:

```
eclipse -nosplash -verbose -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/ -destination /tools/prd/iaa-download/data/downloader/active/eclipse/release_kepler

eclipse -nosplash -verbose -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/ -destination /tools/prd/iaa-download/data/downloader/active/eclipse/release_kepler
```

Comment: please put your enhancement in the original post (you can edit it)

Comment: Only the first instruction is relevant for your question. I have tried it - it works. Maybe you have had some temporary outage of http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/

Comment: look for a *.log file inside the /eclipse/configuration/ folder, it may contain some useful info